# What are the steps and tools used to troubleshoot Entity Framework performance problems?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm looking at an existing system that has a significant performance problem when inserting data using LINQ to Entities. The relationships are complex.

I am familiar with common Entity Framework performance factors such as how often SaveChanges is called, etc. There are two problems with this, though. First, it's not the problem here (the performance problem occurs before SaveChanges even happens). Second, it's just guessing. It often works but it's not a process, it's a hope.

I'd like to know the best way to deal with these big problems the real way, where hope doesn't work. If this were ADO using SQL commands, the tool would be SQL Server Performance Profiler to see how many queries were happening, what they were, what their execution plans are, etc., and then adjusting the commands to mitigate those problems. In Entity Framework land, these tools aren't effective because there is not a 1-1 mapping between what you tell it and the commands it generates, and in this particular case it's not even SQL being slow.

Although I'd like the answer here to be a generic approach, here is the relevant code specific to my current problem:

```
    foreach( var thing in objectsToImport ) {
      var newEntityFrameworkManagedObject = new EntityFrameworkManagedObject { createdOn = DateTime.UtcNow };
      newEntityFrameworkManagedObject.OtherExistingEntity = getExistingEntity( thing.OtherEntityMatchingInfo );
      ... /*Many more lines associating new object to a bunch of existing items selected before loop.*/
      modelRepository.Insert( newEntityFrameworkManagedObject );
    }
    ...
    modelRepository.SaveChanges();
```

The performance hit is on modelRepository.Insert(). We're importing a CSV of several-hundred rows and each call to Insert takes a full minute. Notice that it never gets to SaveChanges. Even the first item to be inserted is slow.

Comment: How do you know if it is EF and not your code? How do you do change tracking? If your entities are not POCOs but you are using change tracking proxies and you do a lot of "associating new object to a bunch of existing " you may accidently make EF react to each change which could cause performance issues. You can read more on this here: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/12/05/should-you-use-entity-framework-change-tracking-proxies/

Comment: @Pawel I don't. And what you are saying is exactly what I suspect is happening; it's basically saying "somewhere, in a location unknown to me, there is code that is probably configuring things in such as way that operations that appear simple, such as setting properties and doing Insert calls that don't actually hit the database yet, are actually invoking tons of magical behavior that is very expensive." Identifying what magic is happening, and why, using a repeatable process instead of just searching through the codebase for the golden needle is what I'm after here.

Comment: Why don't you use a profiler then?

Comment: @Pawel That sounds like an excellent and important part of the answer to this question. And it happens that we did use a profiler and discovered that one call to the Import method is resulting in 20 calls to the Insert method, which (as you suspected) is resulting in 20 calls to the DetectChanges method, which eventually results in 9.2 million calls to get_item() and some other methods, and 4.6 million calls to GetRelatedEnd() and some other methods. So, we indeed have very expensive magic that is not explicitly being asked for in the area of code we are looking at.

Comment: So, it turns out that AutoDetectChangesEnabled is configured by this repository to be true (not anywhere near this code). And, changing its value to false is not possible without modifying the interface of modelRepository to allow access to Configuration. But if we work through all that then it appears to be fast, but blows up when SaveChanges is called. A call to DetectChanges (also impossible without modifying modelRepository's interface) seems to fix that and still perform pretty well. This particular problem may be solved.

Comment: Are we saying then that the entire process is "profile the code" and be aware of particular trouble methods like SaveChanges and DetectChanges? I'm convinced that there are still performance problems caused by Entity Framework magic that are more subtle and harder to solve than this particular one.

Comment: I can assume from your description you are using change tracking proxies which causes calling DetectChanges multiple times. You only need to call DetectChanges once - just before calling SaveChanges. So the option might be set AutoDetectChangesEnabled to false (hardcode) and manually call DetectChanges before SaveChanges. Don't know your code so don't know if it is easier than what you described you would need to do. With regards to performance - you always measure to find hot spots and then you address them. This is always true - whether you use EF or not.

Comment: @Pawel I (well, the original author) am not explicitly using tracking proxies but I believe you when you say it's probably true. And yes, what you describe (calling DetectChanges, once, before SaveChanges) is exactly what I was trying to describe in my previous comment, and it works well. As for performance - EF seems substantially more likely to have unexpected side-effects from seemingly innocuous code that, once identified, are still not clear how to control, than almost anything else I have encountered, which is why I asked if there are special processes to deal with it.